# Issue building for android: package io.devshot.rnmaterial does not exist

Tags: react-native

I am currently trying to build my react native project for android, but I am running into this error:

```
MainApplication.java:7: error: package io.devshot.rnmaterial does not exist
import io.devshot.rnmaterial.RNMaterialPackage;
```

I have tried to search for what package I need to install, but I can't seem to find anything.

I am not sure where the issues is coming from in the code, as this just appeared after upgrading to the newest version of react.

Comment: you can remove `import io.devshot.rnmaterial.RNMaterialPackage;`

Comment: Unfortunately I need this package for the app. I ended up creating a new project and then copied all of my code over. This ended up fixing it? Strange fix.

Comment: If you have copied the code, you must reinstall the modules you have installed.

Answer (score 0):

try to delete the node_module, reinstall and link again

```
rm -rf node_modules && npm install && react-native link
```

Comment: Unfortunately this didn't help!